# Stopping and restarting a file based H2 database from a Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a use case where I need to backup the database. As with H2 the database can be stored in a file, this seems to be easy to just copy the file away. However this should happen while the application is running.

For that reason I have to stop the H2 database beforehand and restart in again afterwards.

I have this simple Spring boot application based on this Maven configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.boot.version>1.5.3.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>
    <artifactId>RestartH2</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And this is the application:

```
package ch.sahits.game.h2;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class H2Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SpringApplication.run(H2Application.class, args);

    }

    //access command line arguments
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // How to stop the H2 database
        // backup the database file
        // Restart the database
    }
}
```

The `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

If this were not file based, I could go through the `org.h2.tools.Server`, I could start and stop the server through that, but the solution is file based.

For the stopping of the database I have found some code in `AbstractEmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer`:

```
  public void shutdown(DataSource dataSource, String databaseName) {
    Connection con = null;

    try {
      con = dataSource.getConnection();
      con.createStatement().execute("SHUTDOWN");
    } catch (SQLException var13) {
      this.logger.warn("Could not shut down embedded database", var13);
    } finally {
      if(con != null) {
        try {
          con.close();
        } catch (Throwable var12) {
          this.logger.debug("Could not close JDBC Connection on shutdown", var12);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

However for restarting the database I do not have no idea how to do. Is it possible at all and if yes how? If this is not possible with a file based approach, how would I implement the backup of the database in that case?

**UPDATE:** Checking the [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#upgrade_backup_restore) there is a command line tool that does the backup, but the database may not be running. There is also an online solution, however it is not clear how such a backup would be restored.

Comment: Not sure if I am missing something here. But Since the database is backed up to a file and you know the location of the file. Can't you jsut copy it to some other location inside your application? You need not restart your applicaion for it isn't it?

Comment: As I understand it making a copy of that file, while the database is running can lead to corrupt data.

Comment: And even if that would work, there is still the problem of restoring: switching the database file while the database is running will not work for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works using the Script tools of H2 to create a SQL backup that can be restored:

```
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    fleetH2Repository.deleteAll();

    // Add fleet records
    String playerUuid1 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String playerUuid2 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    fleetH2Repository.save(new ShipH2Record(playerUuid1, LocalDate.of(1364,3, 14), 3));
    fleetH2Repository.save(new ShipH2Record(playerUuid1, LocalDate.of(1364,3, 15), 3));
    fleetH2Repository.save(new ShipH2Record(playerUuid1, LocalDate.of(1364,3, 16), 3));
    fleetH2Repository.save(new ShipH2Record(playerUuid1, LocalDate.of(1364,3, 17), 4));
    fleetH2Repository.save(new ShipH2Record(playerUuid1, LocalDate.of(1364,3, 18), 4));
    fleetH2Repository.save(new ShipH2Record(playerUuid1, LocalDate.of(1364,3, 19), 4));
    fleetH2Repository.save(new ShipH2Record(playerUuid1, LocalDate.of(1364,3, 20), 3));
    fleetH2Repository.save(new ShipH2Record(playerUuid1, LocalDate.of(1364,3, 21), 4));
    fleetH2Repository.save(new ShipH2Record(playerUuid2, LocalDate.of(1364,3, 14), 13));
    fleetH2Repository.save(new ShipH2Record(playerUuid2, LocalDate.of(1364,3, 15), 13));
    fleetH2Repository.save(new ShipH2Record(playerUuid2, LocalDate.of(1364,3, 16), 13));
    fleetH2Repository.save(new ShipH2Record(playerUuid2, LocalDate.of(1364,3, 17), 12));
    fleetH2Repository.save(new ShipH2Record(playerUuid2, LocalDate.of(1364,3, 18), 12));
    fleetH2Repository.save(new ShipH2Record(playerUuid2, LocalDate.of(1364,3, 19), 11));
    fleetH2Repository.save(new ShipH2Record(playerUuid2, LocalDate.of(1364,3, 20), 11));

    // Create a dump and add a statement to drop everything to make the restore work.
    try {
        String backupFile = "h2.backup.zip";
        String tempOutputFilenName = "out.zip";
        Script.main("-url", "jdbc:h2:file:~/.OpenPatrician/h2.db;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE",  "-user", "sa", "-script", tempOutputFilenName, "-options", "compression", "zip");
        File f = new File(tempOutputFilenName);
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(tempOutputFilenName);
        final ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(backupFile));
        for(Enumeration e = zipFile.entries(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            ZipEntry entryIn = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(entryIn.getName()));

            InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(entryIn);
            byte[] firstBytes = "DROP ALL OBJECTS".getBytes();
            zos.write(firstBytes);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = (is.read(buf))) > 0) {
                zos.write(buf, 0, (len < buf.length) ? len : buf.length);
            }
            zos.closeEntry();
        }
        zos.close();
        f.delete();
    } catch (SQLException |IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Restore
    try {
        RunScript.main("-url", "jdbc:h2:file:~/.OpenPatrician/h2.db;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE",  "-user", "sa", "-script", "h2.backup.zip", "-options", "compression", "zip");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The tricky part is that the Script to create the dump will add create statements for the tables. However when running the script to restore the data, the tables are potentially still present, so they need to be dropped beforehand. This is why the `DROP ALL OBJECTS` is added at the start of the script.

Answer (score 1):

My Solutions :

```
    public class H2DatabaseBackup implements DatabaseBackup {

    @Override // Backup database
    public void backupDatabase(Connection conn, String file) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SCRIPT TO ?");
        statement.setString(1, file);
        statement.execute();
    }

   @Override
    public void resetDatabase(Connection conn, String file2) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
       conn.prepareStatement("DROP ALL OBJECTS;");
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("RUNSCRIPT FROM ?");
        statement.setString(1, file2);
        statement.execute();
    }
```

}

```
public interface DatabaseBackup {

     public void backupDatabase(Connection conn, String file) throws SQLException;

     public void importDatabase(Connection conn, String file1) throws SQLException;

     public void resetDatabase(Connection conn, String file1) throws SQLException;


}
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged.  Please a simple description of why you think this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

What if you back up your DB simple with `BACKUP TO` statement as described in the [H2 tutorial](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#upgrade_backup_restore)?

For example:

**./DB/backup.sql**

```
BACKUP TO './db/backup.zip'
```

**Backup method**

```
public void backupH2() {

    try {
        RunScript.execute("jdbc:h2:./db/data", "sa", "", "./db/backup.sql", Charset.defaultCharset(), true);
        LOG.info("H2 is backed up.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOG.info("Cannot backup H2. Cause: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My working [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/h2).

Comment: Only to backup the database this works out fine, however when you try to load the backup in again you run into problems, as the script does not take care of potentially already present tables. See my solution.